# recursively returning a ternary in python doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, recursion, ternary

the below code prints 1 but should print 24. 
rewriting with a simple if/else works fine.

```
def factorial(x):
  return 1 if (x == 1) else factorial(x - 1) 

print(factorial(4))
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the ternary.  Your code never multiplies.

Comment: `else x * factorial(x - 1) `

Answer (score 3):

It's not a ternary problem, but the definition of the function itself. This should be

```
def factorial(x):
  return x if x == 1 else x * factorial(x - 1)
```